# Errors logged in ELMAH_Error table not showing on elmah.axd page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

Need some help figuring out why my instance of Elmah is not showing errors logged in the DB table on the elmah.axd page. It seems like everything is configured correct, including 'applicationName', but nothing shows in the UI. Please see the setup code below.

Web.config

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web>    
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />      
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>


<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>

<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" 
              applicationName="InfoEx"
              connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
</elmah>
```

ELMAH_Error Table
[image: ELMAH_Error Table]

Elmah.axd
[image: Elmah.axd]

Comment: Do you have a location element in your web.config file and if so, can you share that in your post as well?

Comment: @ThomasArdal there is currently no location element in the web.config file.

Comment: If you can recreate this in a clean project, I would be happy to take a look.